# How combine two excel files with the same columns name same format, only dates are different, and the column order should base on the same column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Table 1:
| date        | weight| height | width|

12/27/2022         1    2        3

12/27/2022         4    5        6

Table 2
| date        | weight| height | width|

01/03/2023          1    2        3

01/03/2023          4    5        6

The combined table should be:
|date1| date2| weight1| weitht2|height1| height2| width1| width2|

Can anyone use python (Pandas) to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, its not the most elegant but gets the job done.  - Listen to Lil Wayne!

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('table_1.csv', sep=' ')
df2 = pd.read_csv('table_2.csv', sep=' ')


# add file number to each column
df1.columns = [x +'_1' for x in df1.columns]
df2.columns = [x +'_2' for x in df2.columns]


# save these for later
df1_cols = df1.columns
df2_cols = df2.columns

# make the final column ordering 
final_col_order = []
for one, two in zip(df1_cols, df2_cols):
    final_col_order.append(one)
    final_col_order.append(two)


# loop through just table 2 columns
for col in df2_cols:
    
    # add each table 2 cols to table 1
    df1[col] = df2[col]
    
# apply the final ordering you like, and copy it to a new df
df = df1[final_col_order].copy()

df.head()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

This will get you half-way there:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df

    date    weight  height  width   date    weight  height  width
0   12/27/2022  1   2   3   01/03/2023  1   2   3
1   12/27/2022  4   5   6   01/03/2023  4   5   6
```

Then you can reorder and rename your columns however you want.

```
# rename the columns
df.columns = ['date1', "weight1", "height1", "width1", 'date2', "weight2", "height2", "width2"]

# reorder the columns
df = df[['date1','date2', "weight1","weight2", "height1","height2", "width1", "width2"]]

df

    date1   date2   weight1 weight2 height1 height2 width1  width2
0   12/27/2022  01/03/2023  1   1   2   2   3   3
1   12/27/2022  01/03/2023  4   4   5   5   6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already read this data into pandas dataframes with something like pandas read_excel since you mentioned it.

Looks like all you need is just a merge function after you read the tables into a pandas dataframe.

> df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')

official docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Your formatting is difficult to read for the table but if you just want to merge them and then change the column order you can use this to rearrange them after concatenating it.

Change order of the cols based on column names:

> df.loc[:,['Column1name','column5name','column2name','column4name']]